# Can't open lib 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0' when running python3 file in Ubuntu VM

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, ubuntu, pyodbc

I am trying to run my python code within a Ubunu VM (18.04.3) but keep getting the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "python-script.py", line 33,
>   in 
>       conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};' pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open
>   lib 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0' : file not found (0)
>   (SQLDriverConnect)")

I have installed pyodbc with no errors so am confused as to what could be causing this issue.
I have done lots of search to a solution but most are for different driver versions and do not resolve this issue. Below is my code for connecting to the DB which I believe could be causing this error:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
                      'Server=servername;'
                      'Database=databasename;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Which version of `pyodbc` did you install? According to the [install documentation (step 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15) it's version 17, not 11.

Answer (score 4):

After you install the ODBC driver according to the instructions at

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

you need to use

```
DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;...
```

Comment: Thanks but I now get this error: `pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')`

Comment: The same issue once I run into containers.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the drivers installed from pyodbc

```
drivers = [item for item in pyodbc.drivers()]
```

Then I loop through it to make sure that it matches what I need

```
for driver in drivers:
    print(driver)
    # Check for correct driver 
    if 'ODBC' in driver and 'SQL Server' in driver:
        useDriver = driver
```

Then it is ready to put into the connection

```
db = pyodbc.connect(driver=useDriver, 
                        server=server, 
                        database=database,
                        user=username, 
                        password=password)
```